# Electric field inside wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electrons, electric-current, conductors

So I m a high school student and I learned that **electric field inside conductor is 0 when it is placed in external electric** field due to induced Electric field inside.
How can electrons flow if E(net)=0
Where am I wrong

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17741/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE :-) Have a read through the answers to [If electric field inside a conductor is always zero, then why do free electrons move?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754949/if-electric-field-inside-a-conductor-is-always-zero-then-why-do-free-electrons) as this is a duplicate of your question.